# browser window.navigator.credentials API to get client certificate header

Tags: javascript, credentials, smartcard, x509, client-certificates

Is there a way from the front-end to query for a client certificate and use its header in javascript?

For context, I am working on an app that needs to read a smart card X509 certificate header, to pull the user's name and ID into pre-populated form fields.

I do not need to accomplish the full mutual TLS handshake in any way - I just want to be able to read the header of their client certificate so that I can auto-populate their name and id into form fields.

I am researching the window.navigator.credentials API to be able to accomplish this - since the variables which I need the header for are all on the front-end.
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Navigator/credentials

```
function cert() {
    if (window.navigator.credentials && window.navigator.credentials.get) {
      const challenge = new Uint8Array(32); // Generate a valid challenge value
  
      const credentialPromise = window.navigator.credentials.get({
        publicKey: {
          challenge,
          // Add any other options or filters if necessary
        },
      });
  
      credentialPromise
        .then((credential) => {
          // Access the credential and its client certificate
          if (credential && credential.rawId) {
            // Get the client certificate as an ArrayBuffer
            const certificateBuffer = new Uint8Array(credential.response.clientDataJSON);
            // Convert the ArrayBuffer to a string
            const certificateHeader = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, certificateBuffer));
  
            // Do something with the client certificate header
            console.log('Client certificate header:', certificateHeader);
          } else {
            console.error('No client certificate found');
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error retrieving client certificate:', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.error('Web Credentials API not supported');
    }
  }
```

When I run this function in the browser I get:

```
Error retrieving client certificate: DOMException: This is an invalid domain.
```